# Does the NETWORK_PROVIDER permission require data?

Tags: gps, internet

If I have an app that checks my location using the NETWORK_PROVIDER permission, does that simple check use up any data? That is, will it use up any of my bandwidth on my paid data connection (3G, 4G, etc)?

With plans that have bandwidth limits, or plans that charge per MB used, I would like to know if an app with this particular permission (and no others) could use up some of my data allowance.

Comment: Have you checked in *Settings→Data usage*? There you can see which app used how much data. Apart from that, if not GPS, where should the location come from? I'd bet you don't have the complete cell tower and WiFi AP location list stored directly on your device. So unless there's a secret other method of transmitting coordinates from your network provider (or that database), it must be mobile data.